# Previous Hour Difference one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to get my output to get me the previous hourly value difference. However, the code below is subtracting the difference with all the data points in the dataframe. How do I subtract the difference row by row. [self.input_item] is my input, df[self.output_item] is my final value

Answer (score 1):

Row difference for dates can be calculated using the below code.

hour['date'] = pd.to_datetime(hour['Date'])

hour['Hours Difference'] = (hour['Date'] - hour['Date'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[h]')

Output:
[image]